# git-lfs pull is blocked at 0%

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-lfs

I am trying to fetch my git repository on an old server who runs on a Linux kernel 3.8.0.

#### The issue

The problem is that running the command `git-lfs pull` returns me :

`Downloading LFS objects:   0% (0/1647), 0 B | 0 B/s`

... and it stays like this during hours.

#### My investigation

- It is likely not an internet connection issue, or an access to my repo issue because a simple `git pull` works well.
- I have tried several git-lfs versions (1.5.2 - 2.8.0 - 3.2.0) and the result is the same for each one of them.
- It may be related to the server on which I work because from my local environment I can successfully run a `git-lfs pull`.
- I tried to re-run a `git-lfs install` before running the pull, but it doesn't get better.

What could cause this issue ?
Thanks !

Comment: This seems like an issue where it's waiting for username/password. Try adding your username to the remote URL like this: `https://username@github.com/yourreponame` and try again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finaly fixed my issue. It turns out it was a SSL certificate error as I once got the error message

```
LFS: Get https://api.media.atlassian.com/file/xxxxx/binary: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

So I added this option to my git-lfs command :

```
git lfs clone -c http.sslVerify=false git@bitbucket.org:xxx/xxx
```

Comment: Setting `http.sslVerify=false` turns off all security for your connection and allows virtually any reasonably dedicated party to tamper with your data.  It's equivalent to not using encryption at all.  You'd be better off actually configuring the TLS certificates correctly for your system, which would allow you to use a secure connection.